# Debezium MySQL (MariaDB) connector : How to resume from a previous bin-log file position

Tags: apache-kafka-connect, cdc, debezium

I am using **Debezium-connector-mysql-0.7.5-plugin** for CDC to connect MariaDB v10.0.32. The CDC records are saved in HDFS for further processing. Everything was perfect until the following situation happened:

1. Stopped Connect
2. Stopped Kafka completely
3. Stopped MariaDB Server

I can see from the CDC Records that the latest processed bin log coordinate is as follows:

```
File : mysql-bin.000008
Position: 2155
```

Due the above actions I am facing following consequences:

1. MariaDB rotates its bin log during restart and current status is like below

   `+------------------+----------+--------------+------------------+
   | File             | Position | Binlog_Do_DB | Binlog_Ignore_DB |
   +------------------+----------+--------------+------------------+
   | mysql-bin.000009 |      326 |              |                  |
   +------------------+----------+--------------+------------------+`
2. My previously registered Debezium connector is no longer available in newly started Kafka

In this situation, if I start from the scratch, the connector will take the initial snapshot with following actions:

1. Place locks then read data from all tables
2. Once done it start reading the latest bin log file which is mysql-bin.000009

Considering my situation, is there any way to instruct Debezium to resume its operation from mysql-bin.000008 - position 2155 and bypass the initial snapshot.

Thanks in advance for your help.

Answer (score 1):

You could try and insert a record into Connect's offset topic, representing the position you'd like to continue from. But I wouldn't really recommend to do so in this case, as you'll loose events between the time where the connector left of and the time of log rotation. So you'd be on the safer side by indeed taking a new snapshot.

Answer (score 0):

As far as I tried , You cant reset the binlog filename and position of the debezium.